# MSAccess Database Integration C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access, dataset

There are concerns about using Access as a database still, but let me clarify my situation. We are developing an engineering based application. So Engineers
should be able to open their local copy of database and modify the values depends on their need. They are not very fluent with SQL commands or any other server sort of things. That's why we chose Ms Access for our application.I did a research on few of the techniques available currently for access database connection and came to a conclusion with following results.

1. [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) : **Looks very promising. Is there any other tools
   like Simple Crud to make the life easier?**
2. [jetentityframeworkprovider](https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/) : **I haven't evaluated much on this.
   Can any experts provide the advantage over Dapper?**
3. DataSet/Linq-to-DataSet : **I have used this, but afraid it will be
   bit tough when database and table size grows**

My database will not be a complex one and some basic CRUD operations. Could anybody advise on above? or if any latest frameworks other than this?

### Edit

I have found [Dapper-Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions). Together with Dapper, It will satisfy my needs

Comment: Jet Entity Framework Provider is a provider for Entity Framework 6 so with advantages (features) and disadvantages (speed) of entity framework.